# Aweber form not working in ios7, iPad or iPhone (but works on laptop)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, aweber

Hi: I'm having a weird (to me, at least) issue with AWeber forms on my site that work fine on my computer, but not on an iPhone or iPad (running iOS7). The site/form are here:

http://www.radionowhere.net

Dropping a valid email into the field and clicking the "Get it now!" button on my laptop (Mac OS X 10.6.8, Chrome/FF/Safari) kicks off the AW process, as intended.

On the iPhone/iPad, however, the button blinks quickly and then...does nothing.

In addition, on the iPhone, once clicked, the button displaces down below the email field.

I can't figure out what's happening here, and would love any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. You need to upgrade your software, the software you use for publishing on the iPad. I too had the same issue with Aweber not working properly on my iPad, returning an "Email Address Is Not Valid" error, even though when testing, I used my own email address which WAS correct. I had to upgrade my publishing software, in my case from Version 5.0.1 to Version 5.0.2, because I was advised by the developers of the software that the latter version contained the "bug fix for Aweber code".

Good luck my friend.
Jen (Cairns, Australia)